# "self" in Django Model methods

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I have some models that include titles starting with "the." I've written a little regex helper helper function to move the "the" to the end (e.g., "The Dogg Pound" --> "Dogg Pound, The"). The problem is, I keep getting `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` when I try to validate my models. I'm not entirely sure why this should be, as I don't think I'm doing anything different than the model method examples on the website. My code:

```
from django.db import models
import re


def de_the(s):
    m = re.match(r'(th[ea]) (.*)', s, re.I | re.U)
    if m:
        return '{}, {}'.format(m.group(2), m.group(1))
    else:
        return s
...
class Album(models.Model):
    album = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist', null=True, blank=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(unique=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def _get_sort_name(self):
        return de_the(self.__unicode__())

    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
            return self.album
        except AttributeError, TypeError:
            return None

    s_n = property(_get_sort_name)
    sort_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=self.s_n)


class Meta:
    ordering = ["sort_name"]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model `class Album`:

```
sort_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=self.s_n)
```

the `self.s_n` should be just `s_n`

```
sort_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=s_n)
```